# Need a solution for using method

Tags: java, class, methods, instantiation

public class WaterHeater{

```
//public fields set to private
private double water = 1;
private double kilowatts= 2;
private double joules = 3600;
private double temp = 70;
private double jkg = 4200;
private double energy;
private double time;

//Constructor method
public WaterHeater (double water, double kilowatts, double joules, double temp, double jkg)  {
}

//Accessors and mutators
//Accessor for Water
public double getWater() {
    return water;
}
public void setWater(int water) {
    this.water = water;
}
//Accessor for Kilowatts
public double getKilowatts() {
    return kilowatts;
}
public void setKilowatts(int kilowatts) {
    this.kilowatts = kilowatts;
}
//Accessor for Temperature
public double getTemp() {
    return temp;
}
public void setTemp(int temp) {
    this.temp = temp;
}
//Method for Energy used
public double getEnergy() {
    energy = water*jkg*temp;
    return energy;
}
public void setEnergy() {
    this.energy = energy;
}
//Method for Time to boil
public double getTime() {
    time = energy/kilowatts;
    return time;
}
public void setTime() {
    this.time = time;
}
```

}

public class Kettle extends WaterHeater{

```
public Kettle(double water, double kilowatts, double joules, double temp, double jkg) {
    super(water, kilowatts, joules, temp, jkg);      
}

public static void main( String args[] ) 
{ 

    userInput kettleinput = new userInput();

    System.out.println("\nEnergy used: ");
    System.out.println("Time to boil: ");

}
```

}

public class userInput {

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    double getWater;

    // These must be initialised
    String strWater = null;
    int    intWater = 0;

    System.out.print("Enter amount of water used: ");
    System.out.flush();

    // read string value from keyboard
    try {
        strWater = in.readLine();
    } 
    catch (IOException ioe) { 
        // ignore exception
    }

    // convert it to integer
    try {
        intWater = Integer.parseInt(strWater);
    } 
    catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        System.out.println("Whoops: " + nfe.toString());
        System.exit(1);
    }

    double getKilowatts;

    // These must be initialised
    String strKilowatts = null;
    int    intKilowatts = 0;

    System.out.print("Enter amount of Kilowatts used: ");
    System.out.flush();

    // read string value from keyboard
    try {
        strKilowatts = in.readLine();
    } 
    catch (IOException ioe) { 
        // ignore exception
    }

    // convert it to integer
    try {
        intKilowatts = Integer.parseInt(strKilowatts);
    } 
    catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        System.out.println("Whoops: " + nfe.toString());
        System.exit(1);
    }

    double getTemp;

    // These must be initialised
    String strTemp = null;
    int    intTemp = 0;

    System.out.print("Enter the temperature of water raised by: ");
    System.out.flush();

    // read string value from keyboard
    try {
        strTemp = in.readLine();
    } 
    catch (IOException ioe) { 
        // ignore exception
    }

    // convert it to integer
    try {
        intTemp = Integer.parseInt(strTemp);
    } 
    catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        System.out.println("Whoops: " + nfe.toString());
        System.exit(1);
    }

}
```

}

Sorry for the long code. I have a problem finding a solution to display the result of the user inputs. I have the methods created in WaterHeater and i want to use them to calculate energy used and time to boil when the user enters Water, Kilowatts and Temp. The methods are already done i just cant find a way to use them. So when the Kettle class is running the user enters Water, Kilowatts and Temp and it will give a result. Any help is appriciated.

Answer (score 2):

I would change the following:
move your code from the userInput main method into the constructor. Then all your variables that you need to use like intWater and intKilowatts i would make member variables. I would then provide public accessor methods.

Then your Kettle class main method you need to instantiate a new kettle and pass through the values from the user input class. Then you can just get the values you need from the kettle class which inherits from that water heater class and provides the required methods to output.

Answer (score 1):

First off, you need to explain yourself a little better. I do not really understand what you really need but here is my try.

**WaterHeater**

- You aren't setting the object's values within the custom constructor.
- If some values are constants, just treat them as they are (`private static final`).
- Values such time, energy don't need to be fields as they are calculated every time the user gets them.

**Kettle & userInput**

- Both have a static function called `main`. That's illegal. I recommend you to move all the code in the latter function into the first one.
- Kettle's main function's code do NOT make sense. That wouln't even compile.
- userInput is a class so call it UserInput (be consistent).

Please, take a deep breath, get focused and explain better what you need and what you already have. Always try to show a code that, at least, compiles.